# Pattern conversion in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, tr

I am new to the shell script, I have a text file with multiple records, and the 1st record end and second record start in the same line as below

```
"-}{"
```

So I want to break the chain as

```
"-} #line1

{ #line2"
```

I tried like below:
Method 1

```
sed 's/\-\}\{//\-\} \n \{' file.txt
```

Method 2

```
tr '-}{' '\n'
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Too much escaping.

Also it's `s/<pattern>/<replacement>/`. There are 3 `/`, the last one on the end.

```
$ echo '"-}{"' | sed 's/-}{/-} \n {/'
"-} 
 {"
```

It's not possible to with `tr`, `tr` is for *single* character translate. If you would like `tr -- '-}{' '\n'` then `tr` would replace any of `-`, `}` and `{` by a newline.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simply substituting `-}{` with `-}` new line `{` and printing the value.

```
echo '"-}{"' | awk '{sub(/-}{/,"-}\n{")} 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'G;:a;s/-}\({.*\(.\)\)/-}\2\1/;ta;s/.$//' file
```

Append a newline to the current line.

Use pattern matching to insert the newline between `-}` and `{` repeatedly.

When all is done, remove the introduced newline.

Comment: Why so complicated vs just `s/-}{/-} \n {/g'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `()` to capture the delimiters and do this:

```
echo '"-}{" -}       -}{' | sed -E 's/(-})({)/\1\n\2/g'
"-}
{" -}       -}
{
```